# Non-interactive drive listing in DOS

Tags: c, dos, djgpp

I'm trying to get a list of all available drives from a C program in DOS (and I don't mean the Windows command prompt, I mean actual DOS 6.0) using the DJGPP C compiler.

I can't find an API to do this directly, so I'm just looping through the drives A through Z and trying to test if they're there. I've tried doing this test using `opendir`, `access` and `statfs`, but in all 3 I get messages like this:

```
Insert diskette for drive B: and press any key when ready
```

Is there any way I can find out whether I can read from a drive entirely non-interactively? If there's a drive present without a disk loaded, I just want to be able to behave as if that drive didn't exist and carry on.

Comment: +1 for the nostalgia of `Insert diskette for drive B: and press any  key when ready`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You want nostalgia? The project this is for also involves an old beige 486DX box with a 5.5" floppy drive that makes an absolutely delightful noise :)

Comment: Hey is that a DX2 or a normal DX? Have I missed those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just shortly after posting this, I discovered that there **is** actually an API to do what I want to do directly, using [setmntent](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_706.html) and [getmntent](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_405.html).

Here's a code sample:

```
FILE *mntentptr = setmntent(NULL, NULL); // this won't segfault as DJGPP ignores both pointers
struct mntent *fsdetails;
while (fsdetails = getmntent(mntentptr)){
    printf("Drive %s is present", fsdetails->mnt_dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [IOCTL Query Logical Drive Map](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/480-dos_fn_440eh__ioctl_query_logical_drive_map.html) to check which logical drive it is associated with. I'm not familar with how that maps to standard C library calls, but you should be able to do it via the INT call directly in DOS.